# How to use postgres or SQL Server with nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I am from .net background and few days back started using nestjs for one of my project.

I love the way nestjs built but few question here.

When using .net I can easily connect .net application with database by using some ORM like Ado.net, EF etc.

How do I connect nestjs with Postgres or SQL Server database?

Whatever will be the answer I would also like to know will that be suitable for enterprise applications?

Is there any reference site?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many libraries out there, and the choice would depend a lot on your experience with ProstgreSQL, and personal preferences. For starters, how well do you know PostgreSQL, do you prefer writing SQL directly or code around it via data models. Performance requirements, and real use cases.

Comment: From my point of view, TypeORM would be a good tool to build solid backend both with NestJS, and it is also backed by quite a good amount of sponsors (https://opencollective.com/typeorm/), and final points it is well documented and overall it has a good adoption by the community.

Answer (score 1):

The docs show examples of how to conenct to a database using [TypeORM](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) and [Sequilize](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-sequelize), or you can roll your own dynamic module with custom providers if you want to use something else. There are a few packages around for [knex](https://github.com/nestjsplus/knex), [pg-promise](https://github.com/rubiin/nest-pgpromise), and [massiveORM](https://github.com/nestjsplus/massive). These should all be more than suitable for enterprise applications, but if anything shows up as an issue, make sure to notify the owners of the repository.

Comment: Just so, worth noting, `pg-promise` is the only one on the list that's not an ORM, it is for executing SQL directly, good choice for those who knows SQL well.

Comment: @vitaly-t you are absolutely right. I just started listing different NestJS database packages I knew of. I ended up rolling my own `pg` module and using it in my personal project. All the others though are ORMs and would work for the case given above.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Thanks for the answer . I tried installing TypeORM with nestjs and it's not working. Do you have any reference ? I use documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/ but still it gives lots of warning.

Comment: What kind of problems are you running into? I have a repository set up that is to show how to test a TypeORM Nest project, [you can take a look at it here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/tree/master/typeorm-sample).

Comment: Could you provide a repo to reproduce @Glenn singh

Comment: @A.Maitre It was node version issue which is resolved now. But I got one new issue. TypeOrm failing for "Sql Server windows authentication". I used this {
  "type": "mssql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 1433,
  "database": "SampleDb",
  "entities": [
    "src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"
  ]
}

But I am getting "Login failed for user '' ". Any suggestions on this. I asked for support on TypeOrm forum but no luck. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: @Glennsingh it looks like you aren't providing a username and password for logging into the SQL server. Can you log into the server locally? Do you know what credentials you use if so?

Comment: As stated by @Jay McDoniel you should provide a `username` and `password` in order to make the typeorm connect properly to the given DB. Let us know how it goes with these infos provided properly

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Yes I do log into sql server locally . We don't need to provide username and password for windows authentication in sql server. This is the reason I did not added in my above json. I found the similar pain here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1660 . But still I am getting the error "Login failed for user" . No luck yet. Thanks.

Comment: @Glennsingh from your local machine that may be fine, probably have credentials stopped in an environment variable or SQL configuration file, but from this new server you'll need to pass a username and password for the user of the database.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I was able to connect with sql server Thanks. One more thing I would like to know, well I am asking a different question here which is not good but I would like to know, does nestjs has something for firebase firestore ? any npm which works with firestore? I can see nestjs with mysql,sql,postgres,mongo. I don't see anything with firebase ? Any idea. Thanks in advance .

Comment: There's probably some npm firestore/firebase packages around. I know I've seen Angular integration with it, so it has to exist as an npm package somewhere, but not that I know off the top of my head.

Comment: @Glennsingh how were you able to connect to MSSQL. Can you please provide your config for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the basic structure I created to set up my current project with NestJS and PostgreSQL just in case this helps.**

1. I added the following packages:

   > ```
   > $ npm install --save knex objection objection-graphql pg
   > ```
2. Created the nest database module and added this module to the "imports" and "exports" within the app.module.ts:

> ```
> ./src/database/database.module.ts
> ```

2. Then added the following files and folders:

> ```
> ./src/database/migrations
>
> ./src/database/models
>
> ./src/database/base.model.ts
>
> ./src/database/user.model.ts
>
> ./src/database/seeds
>
> ./src/database/migration.stub
>
> ./src/database/seed.stub
> ```

3. At the root level, I placed the knexfile.ts

> ```
> import 'dotenv/config';
> import Knex from 'knex';
> import { knexSnakeCaseMappers } from 'objection';
>
> module.exports = {
>   development: {
>     client: 'pg',
>     connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
>     migrations: {
>       directory: './src/database/migrations',
>       stub: './src/database/migration.stub',
>     },
>     seeds: {
>       directory: './src/database/seeds',
>       stub: './src/database/seed.stub'
>     },
>     ...knexSnakeCaseMappers()
>   },
>   production: {
>     client: 'pg',
>     connectio: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
>     migrations: {
>       directory: __dirname + '/database/migrations',
>     },
>     seeds: {
>       directory: __dirname + '/database/seeds/production',
>     },
>   },
> } as Knex.Config;
> ```

4. Then for each new Module, I called the model from the database folder

> ```
> import { UserModel } from '../database/models/user.model'
> ```

That's it. Here you have connected PostgreSQL with NestJS.

As others have mentioned the NestJS manual is a well written resource for a detailed reference.

RON